# Why does rogue game use of these define for objects?

Tags: c, unix, game-engine

Silly question but I don't understand why the objects are numbered with `0, 01, 02, 04; 010, 020, 040` and so on...... in `rogue.h`

Comment: Think about the popcount of those numbers (the number of "one" bits), and bear in mind those are octals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of hard to answer without more context (which you should include in the question).

Those are [octal (base 8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) integer constants, often used especially in older code to define things that combine using bitwise operations.

In programs today you would perhaps be somewhat more likely to see either hexadecimal constants, or explicit shift expressions (e.g. `1 << 0`, `1 << 1` and so on) instead.

I would say that Rogue qualifies as being older code.

Comment: Worth saying that the leading zero in these constants is *important* - as it's that which is specifying the octal nature of the constant, like `0x` does for hex.